# Problem connecting mongodb with mongoose, after whitelisted my IP address

Tags: node.js, windows, mongodb, mongoose, connection

I can't connect to my MongoDb database. I checked several times, my IP address is correctly whithelisted in the network access. And I have the following message :

```
  message:
   'Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that
you\'re trying to access the database from an IP that isn\'t whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster\'s IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/',
  reason:
   TopologyDescription {
     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
     setName: null,
     maxSetVersion: null,
     maxElectionId: null,
     servers:
      Map {
        'cluster0-shard-00-01-216w6.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
        'cluster0-shard-00-02-216w6.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
        'cluster0-shard-00-00-216w6.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
     stale: false,
     compatible: true,
     compatibilityError: null,
     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
     localThresholdMS: 15,
     commonWireVersion: null } }
^C
```

Comment: could you please show how did you whitelist you IP

Comment: Make sure that your IP is whitelisted.

Comment: I went to the Network Access, and I had my current IP address, but that is not working;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by:

1. Go to "Network Access".
2. On the IP Address registered go to "EDIT" Actions.
3. If your IP Address was changed, you will see an option to allow access to the current IP Address, click on that option in order to update the IP.